# error in ico token and ico contract

Tags: solidity, remix

```
function () public payable {
        require(currentStage == Stages.icoStart);
        require(msg.value > 0);
        require(remainingTokens > 0);
```

> Blockquote fallback typos error

```
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokens);
        totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.add(tokens);
        owner.transfer(weiAmount);// Send money to owner
    }
```

type error  i got  . kindly help this

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to a proper setup right now to test your code, but maybe this error comes from a syntax error. Try using `function()` instead of `function ()`.

And btw, I doubt your function really needs to be public. You can optimize deployment size and reduce attack surface by declaring it as external instead.